# Highlight parent menu when submenu is clicked in Jquery (accordion menu)

Tags: jquery, css, menu, accordion

```
 <ul class="acd" >
    <li class="item1"> 
         <a href="#">Parent 1</a>
        <ul class="smenu">
            <li><a href="subpage1">Child 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="subpage2">Child 2</a></li>      
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item2"> 
        <a href="#">Parent 2</a>
        <ul class="smenu">
            <li><a href="subpage3">Child 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="subpage4">Child 2</a></li>      
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>

Jquery:
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready( function() {

            // initialize accordion
            $('.acd ul').each( function() {

                var currentURI = window.location.href;
                var links = $('a', this);
                var collapse = true;
                for (var i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
                    var elem = links.eq(i);
                    var href = elem.attr('href');
                    var hrefLength = href.length;
                    var compareTo = currentURI.substr(-1*hrefLength);

                    if (href == compareTo) {

                        collapse = false;
                        break;
                    }
                };
                if (collapse) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });


            // on click, show this element and hide all others

            $('.acd > li').click( function() {

                var me = $(this).children('ul');                    
                $('.acd ul').not(me).slideUp('normal');
                me.slideDown('normal');

            });




});

</script>
```

CSS:

```
.acd,
.acd ul,
.acd li,
.acd a,
.acd span {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
border-radius: 2px; 
-moz-border-radius: 2px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 2px; 

}



.acd li {
    list-style: none;
}


.acd li > a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 110px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 40px;

    color: #fdfdfd;
    font: bold 12px/32px Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .35);

    background: #616975;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgb(114, 122, 134) 0%, rgb(80, 88, 100) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgb(114, 122, 134)), color-stop(100%,rgb(80, 88, 100)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgb(114, 122, 134) 0%,rgb(80, 88, 100) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgb(114, 122, 134) 0%,rgb(80, 88, 100) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgb(114, 122, 134) 0%,rgb(80, 88, 100) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgb(114, 122, 134) 0%,rgb(80, 88, 100) 100%);

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.acd li > a span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;

    font: normal bold 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #404247;

    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .1);
}

.smenu li a {
    color: #878d95;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2);

    background: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

.smenu li:last-child a { border: none; }

.smenu li > a span {
    color: #797979;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255, .2);
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;

    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.smenu em {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 14px;
    color: #a6a6a6;
    font: normal 10px/32px Arial, sans-serif;
}



.acd > li:target > a,
.acd > li > a.active {
    color: #00121c;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255, .2);

    /*background: url(../img/active.png) repeat-x;*/
    background: #0088cd;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0088cd 0%, #00669a 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#0088cd), color-stop(100%,#00669a));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #0088cd 0%,#00669a 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #0088cd 0%,#00669a 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #0088cd 0%,#00669a 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #0088cd 0%,#00669a 100%);
}


.smenu li:hover a { background: #f7f7f7; }



.acd li > .smenu {
    display: block;
}

.acd li:target > .smenu {
    display: block;
}
```

I wanted the accordion menu to drop down and highlight the parent when the child menu is clicked, the dropdown menu is supposed to remain open for the clicked link with parent li highlighted. If I click on the parent link where the parent has no child, the highlight will be at the parent.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For highlighting the parent add a class called `highlight` in CSS.

```
.highlight{
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 3px 0px #fff,inset 0 9px 10px 0px #00abe3 !important;
}
```

Now this class is added when child element of any particular parent element is clicked.

```
$('.smenu > li>a').click( function() { 
                $(this).closest("ul").siblings('a').addClass('highlight');
            });
```

Also, this class is added to parent which has no child

```
if($(this).has('ul').length==0){
       $(this).children('a').addClass('highlight');
       }
```

Here is a demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rrh1c5d8/1/

P.S: change css of highlight according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try it once i get back to office.

Comment: hi, i have tried but there doesnt seem to have any highlights on any of the parent menu. Any other get around ways?

Comment: @esiaz: please check the fiddle. Once you select the child. parent gets highlighted. And the third parent without child gets highlighted once clicked!

Comment: have tried but the class highlight does not seem to get applied to the relative parent. any other work around ways?

Comment: i change highlight to 'active' and now the highlighting is visible. However the highlighting only stays for a sec and disappears when the page loads finish.

Comment: Expected behavior if you change class name to active.  active is a pseudo class in css and it will only stay highlighted till the mouse click. Better change to visited if you want to change class name.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the fiddle-http://jsfiddle.net/rrh1c5d8/1/ 
It works fine with highlight class.

Comment: hi gotten the highlight class to work, however i have to append '#' to all my url in order to load the highlight class. And upon loading of page it won't be highlighted until i reclick on the same sub link. This is quite strange..

Comment: is it because i have two different actions "$('.acd ul').each( function() {" and "$('.acd > li').click( function() {" which requires two clicks to get dropdown and highlight to work? can i combine into one?